# Two Java RPC Calls or One

Tags: java, rpc

I have a requirement to return two different pieces of string data through RPC calls.

Would it be better to make one RPC call and return a hashmap with both data points in the hashmap or make two separate RPC calls and return a different string each time or does it matter?  Is there a best practice that I should employ here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're closely related, then it's best practice to return them together... either in a map like you said, or preferably in a UIVO/DTO.

If they're completely unrelated, then you should separate out your RPC methods and make two different calls.

Comment: I think I will use a HashMap<String,String> in my case because this is pretty simple.  Thanks!

Comment: Why not a DTO (a class with your 2 properties)? Should be even simpler than a HashMap...

Answer (score 0):

Reducing the network IO is always good. for your simple case return a Map.